# sorting a mixture of characters and numbers in merge sort

Tags: java

```
public class Mergesort {

    private int[] numbers;
    private int[] helper;
    private int number;

    public void sort(int[] values) {

        this.numbers = values;

        number = values.length;

        this.helper = new int[number];
        mergesort(0, number - 1);
    }

    private void mergesort(int low, int high) {

        // check if low is smaller than high, if not then the array is sorted
        if (low < high) {

            // Get the index of the element which is in the middle
            int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;

            // Sort the left side of the array
            mergesort(low, middle);

            // Sort the right side of the array
            mergesort(middle + 1, high);

            // Combine them both
            merge(low, middle, high);
        }
    }
}
```

I am implementing this code to sort an array of numbers and characters, but this is how far i can go, as far as i know, this code will end up soritng only numbers. How do i frame it to sort a mixture of chracters and numbers?

Comment: You cannot sort mixed things, there has to be something in common, can you please elaborate more on your question, do you want a sort method that can sort both arrays of ints and arrays of chars?

Comment: To make the above point clear, what's bigger, 'a' or 1?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i mean. I want a method that can sort both arrays of ints and chars.. using either selection or merge sort

Comment: You need to make your methods parameterized lets say with a type parameter `T`  and pass a `Comparator<T>` object each time for the specific type of your array and use it to comapre the elements of your array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **char** data type instead of **int**.

Each letter/number has an integer value in *char*.  Using that will allow you to sort it according to that, which may or may not be appropriate.

If you want to define your own order you could use the **Comparator** interface:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

It may be complicated to use this method though.

Comment: is it possible to define two arrays and then convert them to list and sort them?

Comment: Java lists only allow one data type so to get around this you can make a class that combines the two data types.  You could create a new class that has both a *char* and *int* variables.  Java provides classes with a means to determine how they are ordered:  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Comparing_Objects - So you would create a class that combines the fields, add those objects to a java List and then use the  List sorting to order them (or roll your own).